# Trouble converting NVP string to array..?

Tags: php, arrays, string

**Quick version of question**

I'm trying to take a string like this...

```
BUTTONSOURCE[18]=AngellEYE_PHPClass&VERBOSITY[4]=HIGH&USER[6]=tester
```

and turn it into this for logging purposes...

```
BUTTONSOURCE[18]=AngellEYE_PHPClass
VERBOSITY[4]=HIGH
USER[6]=tester
```

**Detailed version of question**

I've always used this function to convert an NVP string to an array without any problems...

```
function NVPToArray($NVPString)
{
    $proArray = array();
    while(strlen($NVPString))
    {
        // name
        $keypos= strpos($NVPString,'=');
        $keyval = substr($NVPString,0,$keypos);
        // value
        $valuepos = strpos($NVPString,'&') ? strpos($NVPString,'&'): strlen($NVPString);
        $valval = substr($NVPString,$keypos+1,$valuepos-$keypos-1);
        // decoding the respose
        $proArray[$keyval] = urldecode($valval);
        $NVPString = substr($NVPString,$valuepos+1,strlen($NVPString));
    }

    return $proArray;

}
```

I pulled it from somewhere a long time ago and I've used it ever since.  Now, though, I'm working with an NVP string that includes [x] values on the parameter names to show the lengh of the value.  For example,

```
BUTTONSOURCE[18]=AngellEYE_PHPClass&VERBOSITY[4]=HIGH...
```

When I run a string like that through my function, though, the []'s are causing it to see it as an array index, and I end up with an array like this...

```
Array
(
    [BUTTONSOURCE] => Array
        (
            [18] => AngellEYE_PHPClass
        )

    [VERBOSITY] => Array
        (
            [4] => HIGH
        )
```

So then if I try something like this...

```
        foreach($string_data_array as $var => $val)
        {
            $string_data_indiv .= $var.'='.$val.chr(13);
        }
```

I end up with an "array to string conversion" PHP Notice and my result looks like this...

```
BUTTONSOURCE=Array
VERBOSITY=Array
```

What I'm trying to end up with is a nice break-down of the NVP string, one line at a time.  So this is what I was expecting...

```
BUTTONSOURCE[18]=AngellEYE_PHPClass
VERBOSITY[4]=HIGH
```

I may be going about this a crazy way that could be a lot easier, but I've never had any issues with this sort of thing until I started working with an NVP string that includes the character count like this.

Any information on how I can resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you updated your PHP version ? I don't have any issue with PHP5.5.

Comment: I'm currently running 5.5.12

Comment: What is the exact format of your string? Why don't simply match all you need with `preg_match_all()` ?

Comment: I provided the exact format (though just the first couple of parameters) in the original post.  It's BUTTONSOURCE[18]=AngellEYE_PHPClass&VERBOSITY[4]=HIGH.  The entire string is just more of the same with different vars and vals.  I'm not sure I understand what you're saying I should try with preg_match_all()..??

Comment: So you want that, for instance `"BUTTONSOURCE[18]"` would be your string key in the array?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I updated the question with a "quick version" of the question that may help, but it sounds like you understand what I'm after.

Comment: @AlmaDo, that's really close, but now it's adding the index numbers at the front like this...0=BUTTONSOURCE[18]=AngellEYE_PHPClass
1=VERBOSITY[4]=HIGH.  Any way to ditch those?

Comment: @AlmaDo, according to the 'fiddle', your answer is fine for 'general' input NVP string as long as they are not urlencoded. I suspect if it is 'urldecoded' first then it would work fine for most NVP's. It is rather neater than my approach.

Comment: Finally read the instructions properly. The supplied code will allow most types of NVP parameters. This may make it more useful.

Answer (score 2):

PHP provides a function to do this called: [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

Note: It handles 'url encoded' characters correctly according to the example in the manual.

As usual, this turned into rather more complex than i first thought. ;-/

Hmm, this is 'quite fragile' as a function - for example you cannot 'urlencode' the entire string and have **parse_str** decode it as the the same NVP's. However, **you can 'urlencode()' any _name_value_pair_ and it will decode them correctly**. This function is 'useful' but **not as general as i wish**.

```
1) The array characters '[' and ']' are used by PHP in a special manner.
2) The parameters may just be normal NVP's e.g. 'Param01=PlainText'
3) The parameter may be URL encoded. e.g. %3CParam42_URLEncodedWithSpecialChars%3E%3DThisIs42%21
```

First, **parse_str** handles all the above formats but the array entries produced are not of a 'consistent' format.

This code attempts to accept the various NVP formats in one string and produce sensible outputs. This should make it of 'general' use.

Tested code: PHP 5.3.18 **[Source Code at Pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/WS00gHkN)**

The function that parses the NVP string:

```
function NVPToArray($NVPString) { // replacement for the original
    $parsed = array();
    parse_str($NVPString, $parsed);

    // convert it to an an associated array with the required formats:
    $nvpArray = array();
    foreach($parsed as $parsedName => $parsedValue) {
        if (is_array($parsedValue)) {
            $nvpName = $parsedName .'['. key($parsedValue) .']';
            $nvpValue = current($parsedValue);
        }
        elseif (empty($parsedValue)) { // was url encoded
            $parsedKeyAndValue = explode('=', $parsedName);
            $nvpName = $parsedKeyAndValue[0];
            $nvpValue = $parsedKeyAndValue[1];
        }
        else {
            $nvpName = $parsedName;
            $nvpValue = $parsedValue;
        }

        $nvpArray[$nvpName] =  $nvpValue;
    }
    return $nvpArray;
}
```

Here is some sample code that uses the function and displays the output:

Data:

```
$p1 = 'ParamNoLength=PlainTextIsItAnArray';
$p2 = 'ParamNoLengthUrlEncoded=EncodedTextIsItAnArray';
$p3 = '<Param42_URLEncodedWithSpecialChars>=ThisIs42!';

$src = 'BUTTONSOURCE[18]=AngellEYE_PHPClass&VERBOSITY[4]=HIGH'
       .'&'. $p1
       .'&'. urlencode($p2)
       .'&'. urlencode($p3);
```

Code:

```
$nvpArray = NVPToArray($src);

echo '<br />Input NVP string:<pre>';
var_dump($src,  __FILE__.__LINE__);
echo '</pre>';

echo '<br />Output:<pre>';
var_dump($nvpArray,  __FILE__.__LINE__);
echo '</pre>';
```

Input data:

```
'BUTTONSOURCE[18]=AngellEYE_PHPClass&VERBOSITY[4]=HIGH&ParamNoLength=PlainTextIsItAnArray&ParamNoLengthUrlEncoded%3DEncodedTextIsItAnArray&%3CParam42_URLEncodedWithSpecialChars%3E%3DThisIs42%21'
```

Output :

```
array
  'BUTTONSOURCE[18]' => string 'AngellEYE_PHPClass' (length=18)
  'VERBOSITY[4]' => string 'HIGH' (length=4)
  'ParamNoLength' => string 'PlainTextIsItAnArray' (length=20)
  'ParamNoLengthUrlEncoded' => string 'EncodedTextIsItAnArray' (length=22)
  '<Param42_URLEncodedWithSpecialChars>' => string 'ThisIs42!' (length=9)
```

Comment: hmmm..that looks like it's giving me the same thing I'm already getting, but then you're just pulling out each piece and formatting the output differently..??  I need the output formatted just like I showed it.